# How to select files according to datetime filename in R?

Tags: r, filenames

I have a set of files with the following name:

```
lineal_fit_coef_yymmddhhmmss.csv
```

and I'd like to select only those files that are just before my starting date; between my starting date and ending date; and just after my ending date.

How would you do that in R? I've been thinking about it but I don't get the way to do that. With list.files? But how would you introduce the condition about in-between dates in filename?

For example, I have the files:

```
lineal_fit_coef_130220183448.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130223113802.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130226043153.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130306094439.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130307094011.csv
```

and my starting date is: `130223193927` and my ending date is `130227122246`.

I'd like to select only these three files:

```
lineal_fit_coef_130223113802.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130226043153.csv

lineal_fit_coef_130306094439.csv
```

I hope you can help me somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the function "file.info"

Use it on your csv files and apply your selection to the mtime column

```
files = list.files(pattern="csv$")
finfo = file.info(files)
finfo$mtime
```

If you want to do the same thing but use the times in the file names, first you have to convert them to Dates, then you can perform your selection.

```
#extract the part o the filename that holds the date
chardates = gsub(x=files, pattern = ".*_.*_.*_(.*).csv", replace="\\1")
#convert it to a real R Date
dates = strptime(chardates, format="%y%m%d%H%M%S")
#perform your selection
...
```

Comment: No. OP wants to search by timestamps in filename. Not by modified time stamp attribute of the file

Comment: While the first part of your answer does not address OP's question, I still would like to comment. It is more efficient (if you only need the time values) to use something like `file.mtime(files)` over pulling all the details, then drawing from there.

Answer (score 1):

How about obtaining the list of file names with **dir**. extracting the appropriate part of the strings with **substr**, coercing them to numeric with **as.numeric**, and finally compare using **<** to choose the files you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom function something like below

```
list.files.by.date <- function(from,to,...) {
  filelist <- list.files(...)
  timestamps <- as.POSIXct(gsub('.*([0-9]{12})+.*','\\1',filelist), format='%y%m%d%H%S', tz='GMT' )
  fromtime <- as.POSIXct(from,, format='%y%m%d%H%S', tz='GMT' )
  totime <- as.POSIXct(to,, format='%y%m%d%H%S', tz='GMT' )
  return(filelist[timestamps >= fromtime & timestamps <= totime])
}
```

This will allow you to get files whose "timestamp" in filename lies within range defined by `from` and `to` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `list.files()`, extract the date as a string and convert to a POSIXct. Here's how to get the dates:

```
fileDates <- as.POSIXct(substr(list.files(pattern="lineal_fit_coef_[0-9]*\\.csv"),17,28), format="%y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

And then you can compare these to your start and end dates, and use the result as an *index vector* to `list.files()`:

```
startingDate <- as.POSIXct("130223193927", format="%y%m%d%H%M%S")
endingDate <- as.POSIXct("130227122246", format="%y%m%d%H%M%S")

list.files(pattern="lineal_fit_coef_[0-9]*\\.csv")[fileDates >= startingDate & fileDates <= endingDate]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works only to specifics case):

```
files <- c('lineal_fit_coef_130220183448.csv','lineal_fit_coef_130223113802.csv','lineal_fit_coef_130226043153.csv','lineal_fit_coef_130306094439.csv','lineal_fit_coef_130307094011.csv')
filesDATE <- as.double(gsub('[^0-9]', '', files))

files[filesDATE >= 130223193927 & filesDATE <= 130227122246]
```

(Your example is correct? I got different values)